# Manipulating Account information using Visualforce Remoting

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting

Can anyone tell me how to display account details using visualforce Javascript Remoting?

I wanna edit ,save and validate  the account using viusalforce remoting(Manipulate account details using Javascript Remoting)

Answer (score 1):

As your question is not where to find documentation on either apex or javascript remoting, i'm assuming you know how to write these.

You'll have to create an apex remote method, likely in your page controller. In that method you can query for account details, and return it.  JS remote methods can take parameters, so you could filter based on any parameters from your page.  The javascript receiving the data receives this as a javascript object, which you can use to bind to or create the HTML you want to use to visualize the account details.

For editing, validating and saving you could build additional methods you call from javascript, or handle them in a single method.

Comment: Can you give me the code for editing the record using javascript remoting

Comment: Have you tried writing that code, or what is blocking you from writing that code ? Please see this and other communities as a place where you can learn rather than a place where you can ask people to do things for you.